# Child goes on an adventure and comes back with a black rock of pure evil

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I remember is the last scene as it was deemed "too scary" for me to watch, but I slipped into the room and watched the last bit of it.

Time frame: Pre-2000

The boy in the film wakes up and the house is on fire. He and his parents run outside, the firefighters come and put out the fire. One of the firemen carry a microwave out and says "This seems to be the cause of the fire". The parents open the microwave and inside is a black chunk of rock. The boy yells at his parents (in a British accent) "Don't touch it, it's evil". They touch it anyways and promptly disappear and then the movie ends.

Comment: As mentioned below, the movie is "Time Bandits." I also have fuzzy, and vaguely scary memories of it from childhood.  I did recently rewatch it as an adult, however  --and was surprised to find it was exactly as bizarre as I remembered it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That movie name is "[Time Bandits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081633/)" from 1981

You can see the ending below.

Comment: Oh wow. That video was just... wat.

Comment: @Davor you should watch the *rest* of the movie.

Comment: @Davor Welcome to England in the 80s

Answer (score 21):

The movie you are looking for is [Time Bandits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081633/combined) (1981). The scene you are talking about is from the very end of the movie (after the dramatic conclusion).

The thing I liked about the movie was its charming quirkiness. A young boy travels through time with a bunch of rogue dwarves working for The Supreme Being. Starring John Cleese and Sean Connery, written by Michael Palin & Terry Gilliam, directed by Terry Gilliam - how could you go wrong?

Comment: As well as John Clese, it was ritten and directed by a pair of the Monty Pythons as well, if memory serves.

Comment: You are correct - written by Michael Palin &
Terry Gilliam, directed by Terry Gilliam.

Comment: John *Cleese* (sp)

Comment: I don't think the word midget is considered appropriate any more: http://www.rogerebert.com/rogers-journal/dwarfs-little-people-and-the-m-word

Comment: @Richard You're right, I must have still been half asleep when I was writing my answer.

Comment: I hadn't remembered that it contained both John Cleese and Sean Connery (<- Crush)... I must watch it again soon.

Comment: @Donald.McLean - I don't think "dwarves" is any better. It;'s described as the equivalent of the n-word for little people.

Comment: @Richard - The characters in question work for The Supreme Being, so it is not clear whether or not they are human (regardless of who portrays them). I went with dwarves because that's how they are described in the IMDB synopsis.